# How to add boot sector to Seagate Video HDD

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub, hard-disk, mbr

The internal HDD in my Inspiron 1525 laptop isn’t working so I am trying to install Arch on an external HDD, namely a Seagate Video 3.5 HDD.

I created a DOS partition table of an ext2 boot partition, a swap partition and an ext4 root partition. I’m using MBR/DOS as my ancient laptop doesn’t support UEFI.

I then tried untarring the Arch tarball in the root partition and doing the install from there (using the guide on bootstrapping Arch from the wiki), but when I try to boot from the new HDD, I get a “No boot sector in usb device” error. I installed and configured grub properly during the install.

Everything else seems fine, when I run `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /dev/sdc` where sdc is the new HDD with the arch install, it brings me to a tty.

Is it possible to create a boot sector on this sort of HDD, or it is just not meant for this sort of thing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to have grub installed to MBR with is a drive's boot sector for old BIOS boot. Newer systems use UEFI and gpt partitioning. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Boot info scanning BIOS-Session is taking hours. Is this normal?

Comment: No, depending on number of partitions, it may take a minute or two. It is then saying it is having trouble scanning a drive or partition. You may need partition repairs like fsck or Windows chkdsk on NTFS. Or disconnect other drives, so problem drive not seen.

Comment: Removing the problem drive did the trick, I got this boot-info summary: http://sprunge.us/fOCaL7 . /dev/sda is the USB that I'm running Linux Mint LiveCD on, /dev/sdb is the video HDD I'm trying to install Arch to

Comment: Looks like standard old BIOS/MBR type configuration. I might try the default fix that Boot-Repair suggests. Is this newer UEFI system, and you need UEFI settings changed to BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot mode? A UEFI/BIOS update often resets to defaults and you have to redo some settings in UEFI.

Comment: Working now. I looked at fstab file and it was empty so I added my partitions to it. Dunno if that or the Boot Repair was what solved it, but it seems to be working now. Cheers @oldfred